# Can you get the domain UDP data was sent to using Rust UDP sockets?

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, udp

I have a small program that looks like the following:

```
let sock = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:1024").unwrap();
let mut buf = [0; 10000];
loop {
    let (len, src) = sock.recv_from(&mut buf).unwrap();
    let buf = &mut buf[..len];

    // do stuff
}
```

Let's say someone sends data to `example.com:1024`, is there any way to know they sent the data to `example.com` and not just the source IP address?

Comment: No. By the time it gets to UDP it is all IP addresses.

Comment: If you control the sending code, you could have the sender embed the domain name into the packet's data-payload in some fashion.

Comment: This is generally not possible, be it Rust or some other environment, be it TCP, UDP. (But you can do what @JeremyFriesner suggests, e.g. like the `Host: ` header in HTTP, or like SNI in TLS - but beware that this information is client-provided and thus not to be trusted.)